# BeforeDelete Trigger on ContentDocumentLink object not firing

Tags: apex, trigger, content

I have a trigger on `ContentDocumentLink` object. I have use case to show total number of Files and number of notes attached if the link was between Events and Content using [**Salesforce Content**](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=content_about.htm&language=en). And, offcourse, similar thing that needs to be done when a content is removed.

**Code**

```
trigger ContentDocumentLinkTrg on ContentDocumentLink (after insert, before delete)  
{
    //Check if customization is not enable through custom settings
    if(!CustomSettingsUtil.IsCustomizationEnabled())
    {
        return;
    }
    String BeforeOrAfter = (Trigger.isBefore ? 'Before' : 'After');
    String TriggerType = ''
        + (Trigger.isDelete ? 'Delete' : '')
        + (Trigger.isInsert ? 'Insert' : '');
    system.debug(BeforeOrAfter + ' ' + TriggerType);
    // run TriggerHandler
    new ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler().run();

}
```

Checking the debug log, it is entering the `AfterInsert` event but not `BeforeDelete`. I see no restrictions in the SF documentation, can anyone put some light on this, please.

**Edit**

I'm having this issue on Lightning while on SF-Classic this functionality is working fine.

Comment: In this post is some info that may help: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000ZlQjQAK, it seems to be a salesforce issue.

Comment: Problem is- it's not official.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn´t mean the bug doesn´t exist. If you don´t find a solution to your problem, you can try the workaround suggested in this comments and try to create a trigger on the ContentDocument.

Comment: The problem with the suggested approach is, in lightning experience, users can go to a file/note and then relate it to an event or any other entity. And likewise those can be unrelated. But the content (file/note) are still in the system only the link is created/broken. If I go with suggested solution, I have to rely on entire file/note deletion. Not gonna fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Please vote on this idea to have this fixed:
[https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LqYeQAK](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LqYeQAK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is quite late response, I totally forgot about this question. Anyhow, just updating this question so that if anyone does encounter such an issue, he/she may find solace.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or by-design, but when you delete a **Content** link between two objects in **Salesforce Lightning**, `ContentDocumentLink` trigger works fine but when a user delete the content in **Salesforce Classic** from the **Files** or **Notes** related list following happens

- **file** or **note** itself gets deleted but the `ContentDocumentLink` trigger doesn't fire
- `ContentDocumentLink` is also not fired if user deletes the file/note through **Chatter**

I believed it should, as the File/Note is deleted its link also gets deleted but the trigger never fired. I logged a case with Salesforce but as usual for **technical** queries I didn't get any helpful response.

So I implemented two more triggers to handle this

1. a trigger on **ContentDocument** object to handle deletion of Note/File itself.
2. a trigger on **FeedItem** object to handle content deletion from **Chatter**.

Answer (score 0):

I have been hitting a similar issue recently, after some discussion with a colleague and head scratching I worked around this limitation in a slightly different way. As this question was one of the first I came across when investigating, I thought it might be helpful to share the approach taken to resolve the issue when deleting a content document in lightning.

When deleting the content document in lightning, unless the user selects the "Remove from Record" option in the files list, the `ContentDocumentLink` after delete trigger does not run.

To work around this the following can be implemented on the `ContentDocument` trigger handler so that the `ContentDocumentLink` trigger handler is correctly called to do any clean up tasks.

```
public static void handleAfterDelete(Map<Id,ContentDocument> oldContentDocumentMap) {
    handleDocumentLinkDeleteSteps(oldContentDocumentMap.keySet());
}

@future
public static void handleDocumentLinkDeleteSteps(Set<Id> contentDocumentIds){
    List<ContentDocumentLink> deletedContentDocumentLinks = [Select Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId From ContentDocumentLink Where ContentDocumentId IN :contentDocumentIds ALL ROWS];
    if(!deletedContentDocumentLinks.isEmpty()){
        ContentDocumentLinkHandler.handleAfterDeletion(deletedContentDocumentLinks);
    }
}
```

This then accounts for the lack of ContentDocumentLink after delete trigger event by calling the process for the deleted records. One thing to note, the fields on the `ContentDocumentLink` required in the trigger must be included in the query in the future method.